# PHP String Comparision is there a different between single quote and double quotes?

Tags: php

This is a simple but tricky

Question is Is there different in following two IF Statement comparisons (Note Quotes)

```
if ($retry_type == 'new')
```

AND

```
if ($retry_type == "new")
```

I know there is difference between

```
printf("something $var")
```

AND

```
printf('something $var')
```

Comment: Answer: No (there is not much to add). You can now delete your question, it's too broad and of trivial material.

Comment: Ricers beware: I'm going to downvote any answer that mentions "performance" as a difference.

Comment: A question back: Why do you consider that tricky?

Comment: @hakre people who know about php well know these are tricky if you look at the "cHao" answer below will tell you that you still have to learn lot about the trivial things

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there's no difference.

There is one other difference besides the ability to interpolate variables, though:  In a single-quoted string, the only escape sequences that mean anything are `\'` and `\\`.  All others are ignored; for example, `'\n'` actually consists of a backslash and a 'n', whereas `"\n"` is interpreted as a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example:

```
var_dump('new' === "new");
```

Run it. Examine it. Answer your own question.

Comment: +1 ... we probably shouldn't have 'answered', now he/she can't delete the post :/

Comment: @iight: yes, but I hope this also protects from answers that try to explain the obvious with many words.

Comment: well in your answer I like the sentence "A string is a string".

Answer (score 1):

Nope. A string is a string.

only exception is that if you use double quotes, you can throw in $variables too.

Comment: @cHao lol thanks, was just about to edit it